# Compare 2 columns between different worksheets then paste values

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 worksheets (S1 & S2). I need a macro in S1 that will copy all the visible rows to S2 if the values of Columns B & C of every rows in S1 is not yet existing or equal to any row values in Worksheet S2 Columns D & E.

**Worksheet S1:**

[image: Worksheet S1]

**Worksheet S2:**

[image]

**Expected Result in S2 when the Button is Clicked:**

[image]

This is what I have so far:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = Sheets("S1").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
Dim rng As Range
Dim foundVal As Range
For Each rng In Sheets("S1").Range("A2:A" & LastRow)
    Set foundVal = Sheets("S2").Range("A:A").Find(rng, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    If foundVal Is Nothing Then
    
    If rng.EntireRow.Hidden = False Then
            rng.EntireRow.Copy
            Sheets("S2").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End If
            
            
    End If
Next rng
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Copy Missing Data Using `RemoveDuplicates`

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub copyMissing()
    
    ' Constants
    Const sName As String = "S1"
    Const dName As String = "S2"
    
    ' Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Source
    Dim strg As Range: Set strg = wb.Worksheets(sName).Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = strg.Resize(strg.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)
    
    ' Destination
    Dim dtrg As Range: Set dtrg = wb.Worksheets(dName).Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Dim dCell As Range: Set dCell = dtrg.Cells(1).Offset(dtrg.Rows.Count)
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dCell.Resize(srg.Rows.Count, srg.Columns.Count)
    Set dtrg = dtrg.Resize(dtrg.Rows.Count + srg.Rows.Count)
    
    ' Copy and Remove Duplicates
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    drg.Value = srg.Value
    dtrg.RemoveDuplicates Array(1, 2, 3), xlYes
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

```
Sub copyMissing2()
    
    ' Constants
    Const sName As String = "S1"
    Const dName As String = "S2"
    
    ' Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Source
    Dim strg As Range: Set strg = wb.Worksheets(sName).Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = strg.Resize(strg.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)
    
    ' Destination
    Dim dtrg As Range: Set dtrg = wb.Worksheets(dName).Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    Dim dCell As Range: Set dCell = dtrg.Cells(1).Offset(dtrg.Rows.Count)
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ' Copy
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dCell.Resize(srg.Rows.Count)
    drg.Value = srg.Columns(1).Value
    Set drg = drg.Offset(, 3).Resize(, 2)
    drg.Value = srg.Columns(2).Resize(, 2).Value
    
    ' Remove Duplicates
    Set dtrg = dtrg.Resize(dtrg.Rows.Count + srg.Rows.Count)
    dtrg.RemoveDuplicates Array(1, 4, 5), xlYes
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```

Comment: This one worked! Thanks! but how can I paste the values on S1 Column B to S2 Column D and S1 Column C to S2 Column E?

Comment: `A` to `A`? Do you have more than 3 columns in `S1`? Is there data in columns `B:C` of `S2`? Do clarify a little bit. I only now saw your new image. I'll try to figure out something.

Comment: In S1 I have 3 Columns and 5 columns in S2. Sorry I just noticed that the image I uploaded a while ago was wrong. I just updated it now.

Comment: I just uploaded an edit that should work for you.

Comment: I encountered another problem. It will also copy all the hidden rows. How can I only copy the visible rows?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that in your sheet S2 you have only unique data before the copy. In that case it is probably much easier to first copy *all* data (except the header row) from sheet S1 to S2 and then use the remove duplicates function.

```
Sub copyUnique()
    Dim LastRowSource As Long, LastRowDest As Long
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet
    
    Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("S1")
    Set wsDest = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("S2")
    
    LastRowSource = wsSource.Cells(wsSource.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
    LastRowDest = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
    
     wsSource.Range("A2:C" & LastRowSource).Copy wsDest.Range("A" & LastRowDest + 1)
    ' Remove the duplicates
    With wsDest.Range("A2:C" & (LastRowDest + LastRowSource - 1))
        .RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3), Header:=xlYes
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: When I run it the 2nd time it seems that it the 1st row was copied again

Comment: It seems that `RemoveDuplicate` doesn't like Dates that are formatted differently. I changed the code so that now real Copy&Paste is used, that copies also the number format.